# What's the most painless way to have a python-only server up and running on amazon EC2?

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, bottle, web-development-server

I've recently launched a linux EC2 instance with Apache + php. My php code eventually watered down to merely calling python from the shell, and nothing more. It's quite an ugly solution, but it works. So, basically my questions are:

1. Just how bad/inefficient/silly is it to have a php code that
   repeatedly calls exec(python my_script.py) rather than a solution
   that's more native to python? I'm assuming it's wasteful, but I'm trying to understand if I ought fret about it or just keep on chugging.
2. I managed to get bottle.py up and running, and was just on the brink of replacing my "stupid" solution with a continuously running bottle script, that seems more natural. But I failed to integrate this solution with Apache via mod_wsgi, I think it has to do with python versions incompatibility issue that I'm loath to deal with.
3. Considering (2), what are the repercussions of bypassing Apache entirely and simply calling a bottle script with a "run" command to listen to all incoming communication? It seems ugly, but is it inefficient or bad in any way? If not, I'll just go ahead and call that my solution... But I'm concerned that there might be a reason for people to integrate with Apache.

Any input would be appreciated. A decent amazon AMI that already runs python 2.7 and processes incoming request by python by default would be nice. Someone saying authoritatively that I shouldn't mess about with this whole apache/mod_wsgi business and just call "bottle" as a script would be best :-)

**EDIT**: I have python 2.7 running bottle with paste as my webserver. Do I have any **REAL** reason to prefer apache over this solution? and while I'm at it, does anyone have experience with enabling ssl in this enviornment?

Cheers,
Uri

Comment: Couldn't you just setup some sort of [CGI script](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html) and let apache deal with how to parse it?

Comment: CGI as I understand it means every incoming request to the server starts a new python interpreter. That's my current solution, and I'm trying to avoid it...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just spin up a Beanstalk instance with Python and let Amazon deal with those details? Beanstalk runs on EC2. Seams silly to make your own spaghetti when Amazon has already made you penne vodka! Lame metaphors aside, I think you'll save yourself the added stress and no need to mix PHP/Python.

Comment: Thanks kevin. I just launched a dummy beanstalk solution and it defaults to python 2.6.8. It looks like quite a bit of hassle to have it upgraded (god knows it wasn't easy getting my current EC2 instance with python 2.7!)... If you know a good guide for how to start a beanstalk python 2.7 I'd be happy to know about it :-)

Comment: Ugh, sorry Uri - should have seen that. Well if you still want to avoid mod_wsgi and you're not partial to Amazon, you could check out Google App Engine - they default to Python and it's really easy to get started there too (I think easier than the Beanstalk).

Comment: For Python 2.7 you can configure Elastic Beanstalk see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update python version on beanstalk I would recommend two options:

1. Create custom ami based on standard ami of beanstalk. Good article here: http://blog.jetztgrad.net/2011/02/how-to-customize-an-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-instance/
2. Customize instance with help of elastic beanstalk configuration files. Have a look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for OpDemand.

Most painless would be to use a pre-rolled AMI, but those become impossible to manage.

If you're looking for something more flexible, [OpDemand](http://www.opdemand.com/) offers EC2 templates for Python applications that you can deploy with one click.  They're vanilla Ubuntu 12.04 LTS boxes with Nginx in front of [Procfile](http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/)-defined web workers.  It's a lot like Heroku, but it's all run out of your own EC2 account.  The [example Python application](https://github.com/opdemand/example-python-flask) uses Flask, but it's trivial to switch to Bottle.

Best of luck!